# How can I configure SmartGWT TreeGrid to use different types of objects?

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt, treegrid

I have this usecase:

1. I get all of my Customers.
2. For each Cutomer, I want to get his Receipt.
3. For each Receipt, I want to get all ShoppingItems.

From the examples I can see how TreeGrid works if I had a hierarchy of objects of the same type, but I don't know how this would work with my usecase.
Of course, if there's a better component to show this kind of data/connections, that would be good too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Tree` (the model behind the `TreeGrid`) in Parent mode.
When you build you `Tree` from the data you receive from the server 
You can add attribute to each node saying this node is of ***Customer*** type, this one has Customer1 as a parent and is of ***Receipt*** type. Another will be node with Receipt1 as parent and with ***ShoppingItems*** type.
When you build you Tree from the data you receive from the server 
you can in the same time you are setting the type attribute set the icon of the node to reflect the type of your element.
Up to you to set such node as folder or not (for example Customers, Receipt will be folders but ShoppingItems not and will be just a leaf).
Hope It could help

Comment: This is correct but it will also work to use a TreeGrid with a DataSource as usual, and have the DataSource only declare the fields that are common to all objects (an id, parentId, some user-visible title and possibly a "type" field).  You can return additional fields - different fields for each object type - in your actual DSResponse.  These additional fields are then accessible via Record.getAttribute("fieldName").