# custom treenode smartgwt

Tags: gwt, smartgwt, treenode, treegrid

I am very inexperienced with SmartGWT and have the following issue:

I managed to make a Library of different kinds of documents in a tree.

For some documents I want to show three icons, which are representing links to other websites, further i want to show some description under them.

I tried to write my own CustomTreeNode, also I looked at setCellFormatter() and tried to overwrite it with no luck.

Can you give me some Tips and hints how to achieve the desired functionality and what I have to keep in mind?

Or are there some good tutorials or books on smartGWT besides the apidocs and the smartclient forum?

Any help greatly appreciated!!

This is what the tree should kinda look like:

[+]node1 
[+]node2 
[-]node3 
     - documentEntry 
[+]node4 
[-]node5 
    - custom documentEntry 
         IMG    IMG    IMG 
        description text

[+]node6

**EDIT:** Thanks to the comment I accomplished to code a tree with 3 different types of documents as leafs (.pdf, .txt and link to a web address). They all have a name and different icons and all have a different behavior, when clicked.
But I've got still the issue, that I still have to implement another special leaf, which consists of 3 icons, representing 3 web-links and underneath a description text. 
The icons must be clickable and lead to three different web addresses.

**2.Edit** With trial and error I think i came a little step further. I created a class CustumTreeGrid wich overwrites the createRecordComponent method of Treegrid and draws a dynamic form over the tree leaf. Now I'm fillig this form with text  3 icons and links. Is this the right/a good way to solve my problem, or is there a better way to achief my desired functionality? I hope someone can help me

Comment: Can have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12365887/how-can-i-configure-smartgwt-treegrid-to-use-different-types-of-objects/12368106#12368106 to start

Comment: thank you, I will look at it in a few hours. hope it brings me a step further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there are other ways, but this is what I did:

I made my own class `MyTreeGrid`, which extends `TreeGrid`.

Then I set `setShowRecordComponents(true)` , `setShowRecordComponentsByCell(true);`

and I used the method: `createRecordComponent(ListGridRecord record, Integer col)` and overrode it, to draw a canvas for a leaf. The canvas contains 3 buttons and three images and a description text.