# SmartGWT: custom treegrid with connector lines

Tags: tree, smartgwt, treenode, treegrid

I coded a `CustomTreegrid`, and some custom leafs have triple the height of a standard `Treenode` /leaf. (here is how i did it: [custom treenode smartgwt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13140842/1774526))

But when I want to show connector lines between the nodes with `setShowConnectors(true);`, the connector lines are only as long as the standard height of a standard `TreeNode`.

Whenever a custom leaf appears in the tree, there are huge gaps and the connector lines are only as long as the standard height of a leaf.

I've been looking for days for a way to fix it and i looked in `skin_styles.css`, the functions `setConnectorImage(String connectorImage)`, `getConnectorImage`.
I think the problem is, that the image 'connector_ancestor.gif' is only as high as one leaf and doesn't get drawn multiply times..

How can I fix the gaps in my connector lines?

**Edit:** Here is an image to show what I mean: (since i can't upload images here yet, its a link to imgur.com) https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ujrzl.jpg

**2.Edit** searching the api for a solution I came across this sentence in the description of `setConnectorImage(String connectorImage)` :  **Connector icons are rendered into the title field of each row** and show the dotted hierarchy lines between siblings of the same parent node 

 
-- So it seams I have to play around with the height of the title field, or at least search further in this direction.

Comment: Whenever you're facing an issue related to design, it's always better to attach snapshots describing the same for easy understanding.

Comment: you're right I've uploaded an image

Answer (score 0):

After searching for some time, I came to know that the connectors are nothing but a combination of images named as **connector.gif**. There are so many files combined under this name such as **connector_ancestor.gif**, **connector_closed_end.gif**, **connector_closed_single.gif** etc.

Now I know this is not a good idea, but you can resize these files as per your requirement and I think it should solve your problem.

But again, even I don't find this solution perfect.
So let's look forward to some better answer.

Comment: Funny, I just looked at these images too and I'm going to try this out now! thx

Comment: I tried out your suggestion and changed the height of the .gif files, but they get always resized to the height of 22px , which is exactly the height of a normal "one row" `TreeNode`! Maybe there is some way to make the name of the node 3 rows long and then the connector gets drawn also longer, but I have no clue how to do that.

Comment: I tried further to set the height of a Node with `setRecordComponentHeight(Integer recordComponentHeight)` - the record size gets changed, but the connector lines are still the same.

Comment: That's really bad. I hope you could figure out some way to enlarge the image. I'll also try & will let you know if I find something.

Comment: I haven't been busy on this issue the last days, because i had a lot of other stuff to do..But still I really want to know how to draw these connector lines. I also wrote In the smartclient forum, but did't get a reply. did you find more information?

Comment: No I couldn't find any other solution. Can you give me smartclient's link to your post?

Comment: here you go: http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=24343&highlight=treeTallCell

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to play with    `setShowFullConnectors(Boolean showFullConnectors)` I don't know if it will work with multiple rows records but it's worth to test...

Comment: i tried with no success, but maybe i tried not hard enough.. i will have a second look at it later! thx